# Увеличение числа в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте! Стоит задача выдавать на страницу случайную фразу из массива и вести подсчет того, сколь раз она выводилась на экран. Для хранения количества повторов решил использовать число, которое хранится в массиве с этой фразой. И при совпадении случайного числа с ключом, брать эту переменную, увеличивать на единицу и класть обратно. Проблема в том, что число в массиве перезаписывается всего один раз, а потом снова равно начальному значению. Я так понимаю массив заново инициализируется с исходными значениями. Так ли это и как мне исправить, чтобы работало? Код ниже:

```
   <?php
$phrases = array(   1 => array ('phrase' => 'И один в поле воин!',
                            'number' => 0,
                            ),

                2 => array ('phrase' => 'Под лежачий камень вода не течет.',
                    'number' => 0,
                    ),


);
$from = 1;
$to = count($phrases);
$rand =  rand($from, $to);

foreach ($phrases as $key => $value) {
    if ($rand == $key){
        $i = $phrases[$key]["number"];
        $i++;
        $phrases[$key]["number"] = $i;
        echo $value["phrase"]." повторялось ".$phrases[$key]["number"]." раз";
}
}



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы расположили массив в памяти скрипта и время жизни массива определяется только временем работы скрипта. Для того, чтобы сохранить значение, вам потребуется какое-то постоянное хранилище: файл, база данных, NoSQL-решение, которые будут хранить информацию постоянно.

Самый простой вариант, можно хранить значения массива и счетчики просмотров в сессии пользователя в массиве $_SESSION. Однако, следует учитывать, что этот набор данных будет индивидуален для каждого из пользователей и обнуляться, при инициализации новой сессии.

Comment: Да, я понял, БД сделаю. Спасибо за ответ.